# Video streaming from desktop to iphone

Tags: iphone, video, video-streaming

Could anyone shed light upon how to capture a live video which is on a desktop and integrate the same to my iphone, so that i can view same live video on my iphone. I am stuck as to where to start. If anyone could give technical info would be greatly helpful.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The new [QuickTime X](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/) in [Snow Leopard](http://www.apple.com/macosx/technology/) has support for a new feature called HTTP Live Streaming, which works with clients including the iPhone. There are several examples in the ADC of how to capture from the screen. You would then need to run it through a compressor  (most likely H.264) and use a web server (such as the built-in Apache) to distribute the content over the network.

- [QuickTime Developer resources](http://developer.apple.com/mac/snowleopard/quicktimex.html)
- [Detailed AppleInsider article on HTTP Live Streaming](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/09/07/08/apple_launches_http_live_streaming_standard_in_iphone_3_0.html)
- [HTTP Live Streaming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks for your replay gavinb, 
          Actually i am plannig to write cross platform server and client is iphone. could you please give any streaming examples.
 thanks in advance

Comment: I have added a link in the answer to the main reference documentation for the iPhone.  Since you said you want to have a cross-platform server, you will need to find a suitable H.264 encoder, and http library.  This depends on many factors, including licensing.  Note that H.264 is patent-encumbered and requires a royalty agreement in many regions.